# compiling archived R package (PET) in R 4.1.2

Tags: r, c, .so

I have been trying to compile the R package PET on Fedora 35 (fully updated). It has been archived on CRAN for the past two years or so, but has installed for me before R 4.1.2. I am wondering whether it can be fixed.

I try:

```
devtools::install_github('cran/PET')
```

and I get errors, after a bunch of non-alarming messages:

```
Downloading GitHub repo cran/PET@HEAD
   checking for file ‘/tmp/Rtmp2To7Lw/remotesed66e3dbe79/cran-PET-9793d0d/DESCRI✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/Rtmp2To7Lw/remotesed66e3dbe79/cran-PET-9793d0d/DESCRIPTION’
─  preparing ‘PET’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─  cleaning src
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘PET_0.5.1.tar.gz’
   
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘PET’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c Hough.c -o Hough.o
Hough.c: In function ‘Hough4’:
Hough.c:41:10: warning: variable ‘theta_min’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   41 |   double theta_min;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
Hough.c:40:38: warning: variable ‘y’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   40 |   double *costheta,*sintheta,theta,x,y;
      |                                      ^
Hough.c: In function ‘Hough3’:
Hough.c:118:10: warning: variable ‘theta_min’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  118 |   double theta_min;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
Hough.c: In function ‘Hough2’:
Hough.c:173:10: warning: variable ‘theta_min’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  173 |   double theta_min;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
Hough.c: In function ‘Hough1’:
Hough.c:227:10: warning: variable ‘theta_min’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  227 |   double theta_min;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c PET_init.c -o PET_init.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c amatrix.c -o amatrix.o
amatrix.c: In function ‘RegulateMatrix’:
amatrix.c:234:10: warning: variable ‘tempVv’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  234 |   float *tempVv;
      |          ^~~~~~
amatrix.c: In function ‘RegulateL1Matrix’:
amatrix.c:289:10: warning: variable ‘tempVv’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  289 |   float *tempVv;
      |          ^~~~~~
amatrix.c: In function ‘GenerateAMatrixColumn’:
amatrix.c:784:9: warning: variable ‘onedivsq2’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  784 |   float onedivsq2,psi,pidivDeltaX,costheta,sintheta,of;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c art.c -o art.o
art.c: In function ‘FAST_ART’:
art.c:128:10: warning: variable ‘tempXv’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  128 |   float *tempXv,*tempBv;
      |          ^~~~~~
art.c: In function ‘SLOW_ART’:
art.c:239:10: warning: variable ‘tempXv’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  239 |   float *tempXv,*tempBv;
      |          ^~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c calc.c -o calc.o
calc.c: In function ‘BackFilter’:
calc.c:335:19: warning: variable ‘M’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  335 |   int i,m,n,mm,nn,M,N,OldHeight,OldWidth;
      |                   ^
calc.c: In function ‘CentralSliceCZ’:
calc.c:700:49: warning: variable ‘rhomin’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  700 |   float DC,deltatheta,theta,thetaadj,*realtheta,rhomin,deltarho;
      |                                                 ^~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c cg.c -o cg.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c em.c -o em.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c eval.c -o eval.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c imgtools.c -o imgtools.o
imgtools.c: In function ‘ReadPET’:
imgtools.c:1005:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1005 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
imgtools.c: In function ‘ReadFIFHeader’:
imgtools.c:1148:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1148 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
imgtools.c: In function ‘ReadFIF’:
imgtools.c:1222:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1222 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
imgtools.c: In function ‘ReadAnalyze’:
imgtools.c:1616:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1616 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
imgtools.c:1614:21: warning: variable ‘OffSet’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1614 |   float ScaleFactor,OffSet;
      |                     ^~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c iradon.c -o iradon.o
iradon.c: In function ‘iradon’:
iradon.c:271:5: warning: ‘spectrum’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  271 |     FreeImage(spectrum);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iradon.c: In function ‘loadFile’:
iradon.c:568:9: warning: ‘list’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  568 |   return(list);
      |         ^
iradon.c:404:16: warning: ‘typeF’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  404 |     OutImage = ReadImage(fileName, typeF);
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iradon.c: In function ‘writeFile’:
iradon.c:684:19: warning: ‘N’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  684 |         SaveImage=NewFloatImage(fileName, M, N, _RealArray);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
iradon.c:684:19: warning: ‘M’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
iradon.c:772:5: warning: ‘typeF’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
  772 |     WriteImage(SaveImage, typeF);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c it.c -o it.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c itreadargs.c -o itreadargs.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c misc.c -o misc.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c oradLI.c -o oradLI.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c oradNN.c -o oradNN.o
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c oradSINC.c -o oradSINC.o
oradSINC.c: In function ‘radonSINC’:
oradSINC.c:52:10: warning: variable ‘idx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   52 |   double idx,mintrig,psi;
      |          ^~~
gcc -m64 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fexceptions -g -grecord-gcc-switches -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -fstack-protector-strong -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1  -m64  -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection  -c sparse.c -o sparse.o
sparse.c: In function ‘ReadSIFHeader’:
sparse.c:607:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  607 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
sparse.c: In function ‘ReadSIF’:
sparse.c:657:10: warning: variable ‘result’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  657 |   size_t result;
      |          ^~~~~~
sparse.c: In function ‘MeanFilterVector’:
sparse.c:1537:13: warning: variable ‘area’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 1537 |   float sum,area,*tempVv,*tempNv,*tempKernM;
      |  
gcc -m64 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,now -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -o PET.so Hough.o PET_init.o amatrix.o art.o calc.o cg.o em.o eval.o imgtools.o iradon.o it.o itreadargs.o misc.o oradLI.o oradNN.o oradSINC.o sparse.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `SaveIteration':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `DebugNiveau'; iradon.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `SaveIteration':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `IniFile'; iradon.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `SaveIteration':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `multtemp'; iradon.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `SaveIteration':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `LogFileName'; iradon.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: it.o (symbol from plugin): in function `SaveIteration':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `LogFile'; iradon.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:10: PET.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘PET’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/PET’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/PET’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/tmp/Rtmp2To7Lw/fileed67b515c13/PET_0.5.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestions as to how i can get this to compile? I need to use the Radon transform on some images.

Thanks!

Comment: I could not reproduce this error on R 4.1.2/Windows 11.

Comment: Thanks, @Rui Baradas. So it compiles for you. I gor this error Fedora 35 (fully up to date) and on Manjaro Linux, also up to date. Any suggestions what I could look for?

Comment: The warnings: _set but not used_ is _probably_ harmless. The _may be used unitialized_ should be looked at and maybe patch the source. They may be in the source (e.g.) It was built/tested on an older compiler version and the current/installed compiler has better diagnostics. The errors: multiple definitions (has to be fixed). It's complaining about conflicts between `iradon.o` and `it.o`. Do you need both? You may want to extract the source and build manually if the build system lets you do this (hacking make or sources). Or, would a newer version of PET already have all the fixes?

Comment: @CraigEstey This is an archived version so I don't know if there is a newer version. This package compiled without error earlier, perhaps the version of gcc is an issue (11.2.1). I will probably have to hack it. I was wondering if there was some change in R which was not allowing it to compile. I guess not, since it does compile on R 4.1.2 but W11.

Comment: Win(10/11/Doze) tends to run a bit behind in [gcc] versions. gcc 11.2.1 is [probably] stable, but that's probably the latest and greatest. I'd see if the [R] package manager lets you do "extract only". Then, you can edit files (source files to fix warnings). You can also look at the source `it.c` and `iradon.c` (e.g.). Then, try to figure out why they define duplicate symbols. After that, run the build command on the modified files. Unfortunately, I'm unfamiliar with R's build system, so I'm only speaking in generalities